# Requirements specification for Multi-Channel website

Tags: requirements, mobile, rational-unified-process

The company I'm working on has a RUP-like software development process, with very heavy documentation. Right now we're doing a Multi-Channel web site -it's intended to be seen in Desktop, Tablets and Smartphones- and every version of the site has a particular flow of events and content.

I don't see in RUP an artifact were this differences are documented. I'm aware that Uses Cases must be implementation agnostic -we can't mention any device specific terms- so maybe there's something in the Design discipline that serves that purpose.

If there's nothing like that in RUP, It would be nice to know how another Software Process document requirements for Multi-Channel sites.

Comment: I'm not familiar with RUP, but I would assume that it allows for at least the *context* - i.e. "User uses tablet to... User uses smartphone to..." .  Or is it really designed so that it doesn't matter if you're sitting at a computer vs communicating by semaphore?

Comment: It's not a RUP Thing, it's Use Case Theory: "use case theory suggests that UI not be reflected in use cases" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case)

Comment: Ah, I see.  Why not declare the actors in the usecases to be "Mobile User", "Desktop User", etc, instead of just "User"?

Comment: Or simply declare the devices as non-functional requirements: "The software shall be usable on..."

Answer (score 2):

If your site actually has to work/react differently depending on whether it is accessed from a desktop, tablet or smartphone, then those differences **must** be visible in the requirements and the use-cases.

A use-case should *not* specify that there is a 'login' button in the top-right corner of the screen, but they can specify that a user on a tablet can perform action A and a user on a desktop must first do action B.